# IF 3 or more Conditions QUERY MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Thank you for seeing my question about IF 3 or more Conditions QUERY MySQL.

After I learned from the [Link posted by Strawberry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) in the comments for more info I began to study and improve my question here, after a few days I corrected it from the answer column below and the results were like this I have a new case with my `Query`, hopefully you can help me solve this problem..

Query from Table `HrAttLogs` :

```
| FingerId | MachineIp   | Date       | Time     | Status | Verified | DateCreated         |
| -------- | ----------- | ---------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | ------------------- |
| 2        | 10.20.20.73 | 2020-01-03 | 07:20:13 | 0      | 1        | 2020-01-10 09:50:30 |
| 2        | 10.20.20.73 | 2020-01-03 | 14:05:00 | 1      | 1        | 2020-01-10 09:50:30 |
| 2        | 10.20.20.73 | 2020-01-06 | 17:22:18 | 0      | 1        | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
| 2        | 10.20.20.73 | 2020-01-07 | 16:21:30 | 0      | 1        | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
| 2        | 10.20.20.73 | 2020-01-07 | 21:51:57 | 1      | 1        | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
| 2        | 10.20.20.73 | 2020-01-08 | 06:56:55 | 0      | 1        | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
| 2        | 10.20.20.73 | 2020-01-09 | 21:10:00 | 0      | 1        | 2020-01-10 09:50:28 |
| 2        | 10.20.20.73 | 2020-01-10 | 04:05:05 | 1      | 1        | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
```

We can see where the `Status` field contains **0** and **1** where `0 mean In` and `1 mean Exit`

In the data that I have :

```
| FingerId | ShiftId | DateIn     | DateOut    | ScanIn   | ScanOut  | WorkhourIn | WorkhourOut | TIME_IN   | TIME_OUT | ShiftIn_1 | ShiftIn_2 | ShiftIn_3 | ShiftOut_1 | ShiftOut_2 | ShiftOut_3 | WorkhourIn_2 | WorkhourIn_3 | WorkhourOut_2 | WorkhourOut_3 |
| -------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- | -------- | -------- | ---------- | ----------- | --------- | -------- | --------- | --------- | --------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ------------ | ------------ | ------------- | ------------- |
| 2        | 10      | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-03 | 07:20:13 | 14:05:00 | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    | 00:20:13  | 00:05:00 | 05:00:00  | 12:00:00  | 19:00:00  | 12:00:00   | 19:00:00   | 05:00:00   | 14:00:00     | 21:00:00     | 21:00:00      | 07:00:00      |
| 2        | 10      | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-06 | 17:22:18 |          | 14:00:00   | 21:00:00    | 03:22:18  |          | 05:00:00  | 12:00:00  | 19:00:00  | 12:00:00   | 19:00:00   | 05:00:00   | 14:00:00     | 21:00:00     | 21:00:00      | 07:00:00      |
| 2        | 10      | 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-07 | 16:21:30 | 21:51:57 | 14:00:00   | 21:00:00    | 02:21:30  | 00:51:57 | 05:00:00  | 12:00:00  | 19:00:00  | 12:00:00   | 19:00:00   | 05:00:00   | 14:00:00     | 21:00:00     | 21:00:00      | 07:00:00      |
| 2        | 10      | 2020-01-08 | 2020-01-08 | 06:56:55 |          | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    | -00:03:05 |          | 05:00:00  | 12:00:00  | 19:00:00  | 12:00:00   | 19:00:00   | 05:00:00   | 14:00:00     | 21:00:00     | 21:00:00      | 07:00:00      |
| 2        | 10      | 2020-01-09 | 2020-01-09 | 21:10:00 |          | 21:00:00   | 21:00:00    | 00:10:00  |          | 05:00:00  | 12:00:00  | 19:00:00  | 12:00:00   | 19:00:00   | 05:00:00   | 14:00:00     | 21:00:00     | 21:00:00      | 07:00:00      |
```

On the 5th data line where `DateIn` shows the date `2020-01-09` and `ScanIn` at `21:00:00` automatically `DateOut` shows the day after `DateIn` which is `2020-01-10` (Can be seen in the `HrAttLogs Query`) where ScanOut should show at `04:05:05`. How do I get it? I have been looking for it but have not found a solution ... maybe you have a solution for the results I expect

I have learned and tried to make a db fiddle to make it easier for other [Link here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/brgCC2MLfSvW2cViZDPLxu/7)

**[UPDATE] SOLVED**

To see updates from the case above, you can see the update query at db fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/brgCC2MLfSvW2cViZDPLxu/8)

Comment: Let's start with something simple. I think there are mainly 3 tables in question `HrAttLogs, HrEmployee & HrEmployeeShift`. Give us the data example (5-10 rows each of the table) for these three tables and show us an example of your expected output. Much better if you can [create a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Comment: Hi, @tcadidot0 Thank you for your input, I will fix it

Comment: Yeah, I can see what you're trying to do and I have a bit experience working with attendance data before. I started almost similarly like you with a very long query but after a few tests, my query were significantly shorter and easier to read/maintain. Hopefully we can do the same on your situation :)

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that, I hope you can help me with the experience you have had :) thank you very much before ... and I have updated the data @tcadidot0

Comment: At the moment I can think of three ways to achieve this.. but first, can I know what version of MySQL are you using? Can you quickly run `SELECT @@version` to find out?

Comment: Of course, I using 10.4.10-MariaDB @tcadidot0

Comment: Nice. This version can support row_number so its going to be easier. One more thing, please clarify data on row no 4 in expected output, where the scanin='06:56:55', the workhourin should be '21:00:00' and workhourout is '07:00:00', correct?

Comment: Yes, right I missed it  @tcadidot0

Comment: You need to have 1 special condition for that overlapping attendance date

Comment: Whats is the special condition?

Comment: I'll update my answer with some suggestion. But before that, may I know why you use union? because the second query in the union doesn't return anything if I execute it individually. Only the top query have results.

Comment: I used the query before updating this automatic shift system, in the future there will be 2 systems for shift query where 1 system uses automatic ScanIn and WorkhourIn and 1 other system uses manual method.. it's useful for combining DateOut data where previously DateIn and DateOut are on the same date

Comment: Ok, got it. I have updated my answer below with some suggestion. Can you try if it's working as expected? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for future questions, please refrain from using image when posting. Use text instead to make anyone who intend to help can generate your scenario faster. Please refer the [link posted by Strawberry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) in the comment for further info.

So, about your question, let's start with something simple. Since you're using MariaDB 10.4+, it's a good news since this version supports newer functions; and here I'm going to demonstrate one of it; `ROW_NUMBER()` , refer official [MariaDB docs here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/).

The base query is this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY DATE, TIME) AS row_num,
       id, MachineIp, FingerId, DATE, TIME, STATUS, Verified, DateCreated
FROM   HrAttLogs;
```

What `ROW_NUMBER()` doing here is assigning row number (rank) for each row partitioned by date and order by date, time; which give you this:

```
+---------+------+-------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| row_num |  id  |  MachineIp  | FingerId |    DATE    |   TIME   | STATUS | Verified |     DateCreated     |
+---------+------+-------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
|       1 |   12 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2019-12-26 | 07:54:25 |      0 |        1 | 2019-12-26 11:09:21 |
|       2 |  216 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2019-12-24 | 16:23:10 |      1 |        1 | 2019-12-26 11:09:21 |
|       1 |  272 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2019-12-24 | 07:52:25 |      0 |        1 | 2019-12-26 11:09:21 |
|       1 |  426 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2019-12-23 | 07:43:44 |      0 |        1 | 2019-12-26 11:09:22 |
|       1 |  709 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2019-12-30 | 07:28:42 |      0 |        1 | 2019-12-30 09:54:21 |
|       2 |  913 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2019-12-28 | 14:05:05 |      1 |        1 | 2019-12-30 09:54:22 |
|       1 |  978 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2019-12-28 | 07:22:32 |      0 |        1 | 2019-12-30 09:54:22 |
|       1 | 1468 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2019-12-31 | 17:57:16 |      1 |        1 | 2020-01-02 10:08:45 |
|       2 | 1796 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2020-01-09 | 18:04:37 |      1 |        1 | 2020-01-10 09:50:28 |
|       1 | 1892 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2020-01-09 | 07:51:52 |      0 |        1 | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
|       1 | 2079 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2020-01-08 | 06:56:55 |      0 |        1 | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
|       2 | 2163 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2020-01-07 | 16:21:30 |      1 |        1 | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
|       1 | 2221 | 10.20.20.73 |        2 | 2020-01-07 | 07:51:57 |      0 |        1 | 2020-01-10 09:50:29 |
+---------+------+-------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

Note the `row_num` field at the beginning. Then make that as a sub-query and perform `GROUP_CONCAT` with `CASE` expression on `row_num` to get datein, dateout, scanin and scan out:

```
SELECT fingerid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN row_num=1 THEN DATE END) AS datein,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN row_num=2 THEN DATE END) AS dateout,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN row_num=1 THEN TIME END) AS scanin,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN row_num=2 THEN TIME END) AS scanout
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY DATE, TIME) AS row_num,
             id, MachineIp, FingerId, DATE, TIME, STATUS, Verified, DateCreated
        FROM   HrAttLogs) A
GROUP BY DATE;
```

The query above will return the following result:

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| fingerid |   datein   |  dateout   |  scanin   | scanout  |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
|        2 | 2019-12-23 |            | 07:43:44  |          |
|        2 | 2019-12-24 | 2019-12-24 | 07:52:25  | 16:23:10 |
|        2 | 2019-12-26 |            | 07:54:25  |          |
|        2 | 2019-12-28 | 2019-12-28 | 07:22:32  | 14:05:05 |
|        2 | 2019-12-30 |            | 07:28:42  |          |
|        2 | 2019-12-31 |            | 17:57:16  |          |
|        2 | 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-07 | 07:51:57  | 16:21:30 |
|        2 | 2020-01-08 |            | 06:56:55  |          |
|        2 | 2020-01-09 | 2020-01-09 | 07:51:52  | 18:04:37 |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

From here you can already start to use `JOIN` on your other table(s) for extra information. The last part of the query is just to assign `WorkhourIn` and `Workhourout` using `CASE` expression like below:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN scanin < '07:00:00' THEN '21:00:00' 
            WHEN scanin < '14:00:00' THEN '07:00:00' 
            WHEN scanin < '21:00:00' THEN '14:00:00' END AS 'WorkHourIn',
       CASE WHEN scanin < '07:00:00' THEN '07:00:00' 
            WHEN scanin < '14:00:00' THEN '14:00:00' 
            WHEN scanin < '21:00:00' THEN '21:00:00' END AS 'WorkHourOut' 
 FROM           
(SELECT fingerid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN row_num=1 THEN DATE END) AS datein,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN row_num=2 THEN DATE END) AS dateout,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN row_num=1 THEN TIME END) AS scanin,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN row_num=2 THEN TIME END) AS scanout
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY DATE, TIME) AS row_num,
             id, MachineIp, FingerId, DATE, TIME, STATUS, Verified, DateCreated
        FROM   HrAttLogs) A
GROUP BY DATE) B ;
```

This will give you result:

```
+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+
| fingerid |   datein   |  dateout   |  scanin  | scanout  | WorkHourIn | WorkHourOut |
+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+
|        2 | 2019-12-23 |            | 07:43:44 |          | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    |
|        2 | 2019-12-24 | 2019-12-24 | 07:52:25 | 16:23:10 | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    |
|        2 | 2019-12-26 |            | 07:54:25 |          | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    |
|        2 | 2019-12-28 | 2019-12-28 | 07:22:32 | 14:05:05 | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    |
|        2 | 2019-12-30 |            | 07:28:42 |          | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    |
|        2 | 2019-12-31 |            | 17:57:16 |          | 14:00:00   | 21:00:00    |
|        2 | 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-07 | 07:51:57 | 16:21:30 | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    |
|        2 | 2020-01-08 |            | 06:56:55 |          | 21:00:00   | 07:00:00    |
|        2 | 2020-01-09 | 2020-01-09 | 07:51:52 | 18:04:37 | 07:00:00   | 14:00:00    |
+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+
```

Now I know this is a whole new query for you to work with but like I said, there might be a way to significantly shorter your original query and I was aiming for that in the beginning. Hopefully this will be useful.

By the way, here is fiddle for all the above : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/riiCi8tjtMaBk64fG6hd4K/0

**Update**
For the follow-up question please try the following:

```
SELECT i.FingerId,fs.ShiftId,MIN(i.Date) AS 'Date',
     /*added CASE expression to deal with overlapping attendance date*/
        CASE WHEN MIN(i.Time) >= '21:00:00' 
             THEN DATE(DATE_ADD(i.Date, INTERVAL + 1 DAY)) 
             ELSE DATE(DATE_ADD(i.Date, INTERVAL + s.DayOut DAY)) END AS 'DateOut', 

             MIN(i.Time) AS 'Time',
             s.ShiftIn_1,s.ShiftIn_2,s.ShiftIn_3,s.ShiftOut_1,s.ShiftOut_2,s.ShiftOut_3,
s.WorkhourIn_1,s.WorkhourIn_2,s.WorkhourIn_3,s.WorkhourOut_1,
             s.WorkhourOut_2,s.WorkhourOut_3
        FROM HrAttLogs AS i
  INNER JOIN HrEmployee AS fs ON fs.FingerId = i.FingerId
  INNER JOIN HrEmployeeShift AS s ON s.Id = fs.ShiftId
       WHERE i.Time >= s.ShiftIn_1
         AND i.Date >= '2020-01-01'
         AND i.Date <= '2020-01-10' 
         AND i.MachineIp = '10.20.20.73'
    GROUP BY i.FingerId, i.date
```

Then your `CASE` expression for `WorkhourOut` change to the following:

```
/*added check for date too.. the last checking is for any overlapping date*/
        CASE WHEN i.dateout = i.date AND i.Time > i.ShiftOut_1 THEN i.WorkhourOut_2
             WHEN i.dateout = i.date AND i.Time > i.ShiftOut_2 THEN i.WorkhourOut_3
             WHEN i.dateout = i.date AND i.Time > i.ShiftOut_3 THEN i.WorkhourOut_1
             WHEN i.dateout > i.date THEN i.WorkhourOut_3 
             END AS WorkhourOut,
```

Comment: thank you very much in advance for the input provided, I will correct it soon for the questions I made and before I have never used db fiddle, this will be a new experience in the future

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I have applied a number of references from you to the query but apparently a new case has appeared that I have updated in the question

Comment: Thanks for the update, i try with expression for WorkhourOut but i got error 'i.DateOut' in 'field list', i try in db fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hNQ526fFKKWXfmt8s42HKq/0 may you can check this

Comment: `CASE WHEN i.dateout` is selected from `END AS 'DateOut'` ?

Comment: yes @Aldan .. it's from there.. See this from your original fiddle :https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/brgCC2MLfSvW2cViZDPLxu/8 .. I have marked where I replace

Comment: Alhamdulillah, this was fully successful, thank you very much..and one question related how to delete more field select like `ShiftIn_1`, `ShiftIn_2`, `ShiftIn_3`, etc.. but they need to called on query

Comment: Alhamdulillah, that's good. I don't quite understand what do you mean by delete more field but if you meant to show only selected field, just change the first `SELECT * .. ` to `SELECT FingerId, ShiftId, DateIn, DateOut, ScanIn, ScanOut, WorkhourIn, WorkhourOut, TIME_IN, TIME_OUT`.

Comment: Yes I have tried fixing it in the first but that didn't work with the results of the `SELECT statements having a different number of columns`, maybe because I called some fields for example `ShiftIn_2` on `WHEN i.Time <i.ShiftIn_2 THEN i.WorkhourIn_1`

Comment: No that's in the wrong position. See this updated fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/brgCC2MLfSvW2cViZDPLxu/9

Comment: I have a "New Case" maybe you can help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594384/mysql-query-with-multiple-conditions-check

Comment: Ok, Insha Allah I will try to find some time to look at it later. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just looking for a `case expression`, like this:

```
SELECT
      ScanIn 
    , case
         when ScanIn < '07:00:00' then '21:00:00'
         when ScanIn < '14:00:00' then '07:00:00'
         when ScanIn < '21:00:00' then '14:00:00'
      end as WorkhourIn
...
```

which is extremely similar to the way you expressed the condition in your question. A `case expression` evaluates to a single value (per row)